# RaspberryPi driven LED strip is flickering

Tags: raspberry-pi, led-strip, ws2812b

Supplies:

- [LED Strip](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BKNS7DJ) Please note I'm trying to power 28 of them. ~1400 mA
- [Power Supply for LEDs](https://vetco.net/products/5v-2a-dc-power-supply-w-2-1mm-plug/vupn7753) 5v/2A
- [Raspberry Pi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BC7BMHY)
- [Breadboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EV6SBXQ)
- [Microcontroller](https://vetco.net/products/quad-level-shifter-74ahct125---3v-to-5v)

I am following the adafruit for driving LEDs from the pi.

They suggest wiring it like this (this works great for me btw, no flickering):

[image: https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/64121]

This is how mine is wired:

[image: my wiring]

I'm sure some eyesores jump out at you:

- wiring color
- melted squares from when my ground and power were touching D:
- hot glue around the peripheral wires
- crossing wires at the power supply adapter

I drew a sharpie line on the wires that are ground.
When I wired it according to the guide, that is, with a breadboard that has vertical running lines for power and ground, it works great!

But moving it over to this mini breadboard it starts flickering.
I tried  powering the led wires (circled in blue) with a wire that goes straight to the power supply adapter output (yellow wire), and it was a bit better, but not much.

So does the voltage really degrade that much with traveling across the board to my led strip connectors? Is the breadboard crap? Does having dedicated lines for power/ground make that big of a difference? Do I need a bigger power supply?

**update**
[image: New wiring]
New bread board helped a lot with wiring the power in parallel. I grounded the unused inputs to the level shifter. I added a 1000uf 16v capacitor although a smaller one would have been fine. Also added a resistor as recommended by Neopixel guide. I bought a multimeter and can see that voltage drop is much lower and there is almost no flicker.

The little led just shows when my external supply is plugged in.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Things seem ok, but you may be missing a crucial bypass capacitor across the supply leads. Any 470uF 16V/25V/35V aluminum radial capacitor with as short of leads as possible. They will take the flicker out of the power feeds.

Comment: At the very minimum you cannot leave the inputs of your 74AHC125 floating, tie them to ground. The line driver may be oscillating. Secondly follow as @Sparky256 suggests and add a bypass capacitor.

Comment: You need a DMM to see the resistance by measuring the voltage drop on each joint and wire length. 10mOhm is ok at 1A but not >100 mOhm

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I didn't know what a bypass capacitor was. I read this: https://medium.com/supplyframe-hardware/bypass-capacitors-on-placement-81a4a2f1500a

Comment: If I understand correctly, I put a capacitor between power and ground right where my power adapter comes in to the board. And also put one on the data out pin of the chip, right? Would they both be 470uF? And sstobbe do all unused pins need to be grounded? @SunnyskyguyEE75 I don't know where those ohm numbers are coming from or how I should apply what you are saying.

Comment: Matt do you think it’s time to learn Ohm’s Law , get a DMM and measure your voltage drop and when  and much does it flicker and what rate per second.

Comment: For the rest already know  RC=T time constant is the breakpoint with only 3dB ripple reduction, if the supply can deliver 5V@2A with < 10% drop(0.1), then it’s Rs=5V/2A*0.1=< 0.25 Ohm so T= 0.25*470uF~120 ms . But if the resistance in your connections is 1 Ohm the voltage drops 1.4V from 5V so do not put this much current in a tiny breadboard contact.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand. No, i do not have a DMM and am not planning on getting one, I figured this is simple enough to have a quick fix. I get that a capacitor stores a charge and allows for constant voltage to the circuts it serves. My question is what capacitors I need and where. You say 'do not put this much current in a tiny breadboard contact'. So the breadboard contact cannot handle 5V power supply input?

Comment: If you use electronic designs at your age , you can learn Ohm’s Law. V=IR etc .  The voltage drop is what counts from I and contact resistance R , not the potential V=5V, here for your problem, and C will not help as much. When you short V+/R=I the power to melt is limited by the poor contact resistance, P=V^2/R up to V*I=P= 10W before short circuit shutdown protection trips. So your problem is V^2 / P= 25/10W = 2.5 Ohms to melt your breadboard. And later cause flicker from damaged contacts with high R.  Go read a few pages on Ohm’s Law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These breadboard contacts are not intended to draw more than 1/4A so improve  the connections with many more in parallel for V+, 0V.

Comment: 'improve the connections'. All of the connections? which connections? 'many more in parallel' perhaps link to an image showing an example of that please.

Comment: How about 6 or 8 jumpers in parallel for V+ and V- and to LED from IC and NOT 3.  Proto boards must NOT be used for high current outputs. and if you don’t learn OHm’s Law , how old are you?  You can calculate 1.4A / 1/4. = 6.4 so I suggested 6 to 8 parallel wires to share 1.4A

Comment: Adafruit examples are sometimes done by rookies.

Comment: To be honest age isn't relevant here. If you'd like to ask me more about my background and why I'm not experienced, I'd be happy to oblige.

Comment: I've done some more digging into [capacitors](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/capacitors/all), [farad measurements](https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/capacitor2.htm), [other](https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/4v24c1/d1_mini_level_converter_2812b_led_power_supply/) [examples](https://learn.adafruit.com/dotstar-pi-painter/assembly-part-2) of led wiring with the pi, neoPixel [best practices](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/best-practices), and using a [level shifter](https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixel-levelshifter/shifting-levels)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback so far, it helped guide me on what to research. I'll make some changes according to what i've learned and update my post with new wiring. Looking forward to your input then.